# Infer return type from string parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a function somewhat like this

```
function getObjectFromString(str: string): { loading: boolean, [key: string]: any } {
    const result = {
        loading: false,
    };

    // Set the value of the key based on the input string
    result[str] = true;

    return result;
}
```

If I use use like this

```
const obj = getObjectFromString('foo');

// obj has the following properties:
// - loading: false
// - foo: true
```

The type of the `obj` is `{ loading: boolean, [key: string]: any}`
Is there any way I can make it so the type of the object is `{ loading: boolean, foo: any}` instead, for any given string value?

I skimmed through the typescript docs, didn't find anything useful

Answer (score 0):

I think ensuring a literal type for a key and casting the result to the right type should work:

```
type StringLiteral<T> = T extends string ? string extends T ? never : T : never;

function getObjectFromString<T extends string>(str: StringLiteral<T>) {
    return {
        loading: false,
        [str]: true,
    } as { [ x in T]: boolean } & { loading: boolean };
}

const obj1 = getObjectFromString('test1');
obj1.test1 = false;
obj1.test2 = 'error expected';
const test2: string = 'does not work';
const obj2 = getObjectFromString(test2);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwDKOBeBDANgDwAqAfFALxTFQQAe2yAJgM5QsIqpQD87naWgwjM2NPsggA3HFABc1eVEkz4AbgBQGgGYBXZAGNgiAPbIoqCMADyAIwBWEIwDF4JgLZwkaEkMat+b1RSAAoOeAUvLkxsPCIyAEooAG8NKHSoeCtdeHNUjIKofBNcJi4FbQIWCAAaNML0gG1wgF0FBF1a+vSAXyhcNmSoRqg6KBRqNqhbExN8CFxzPoAyFKKSsrQFGbmFpc0erQMzDigTBwBGSgsrO0cXN08BVBCAcmwOC9eEzXP7C4AdB9gFcqJV8NVfpcgRAOAAma6vHBueBCSBGCBMV6aY7IU7AuEKcJcRFMEyw5QmYBQADuJngAGtsRpcac-giqJYbA4nMBXB4omgQgSfhogA)